# Split list of datetimes into days

Tags: python, datetime, date, grouping

I've got a sorted list of datetimes: (with day gaps)

```
list_of_dts = [
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0), 
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,1,0,0), 
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,0,0,0), 
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,3,0,0,0),
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,5,0,0,0),
              ]
```

And I'd like to split them in to a list for each day:

```
result = [
          [datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0), datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,1,0,0)],
          [datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,0,0,0)],
          [datetime.datetime(2012,1,3,0,0,0)],
          [], # Empty list for no datetimes on day
          [datetime.datetime(2012,1,5,0,0,0)]
         ]
```

Algorithmically, it should be possible to achieve at least O(n).

Perhaps something like the following:
(This obviously doesn't handle missed days, and drops the last dt, but it's a start)

```
def dt_to_d(list_of_dts):
    result = []
    start_dt = list_of_dts[0]
    day = [start_dt]
    for i, dt in enumerate(list_of_dts[1:]):
        previous = start_dt if i == 0 else list_of_dts[i-1]
        if dt.day > previous.day or dt.month > previous.month or dt.year > previous.year: 
            # split to new sub-list
            result.append(day)
            day = []
            # Loop for each day gap?
        day.append(dt)
    return result
```

Thoughts?

Comment: use a dict of lists with datetime_value.date() as keys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to go is to use [dict.setdefault](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to group entries falling on the same day and then loop over the lowest day to the highest:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> list_of_dts = [
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0),
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,1,0,0),
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,0,0,0),
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,3,0,0,0),
              datetime.datetime(2012,1,5,0,0,0),
              ]

>>> days = {}
>>> for dt in list_of_dts:
        days.setdefault(dt.toordinal(), []).append(dt)

>>> [days.get(day, []) for day in range(min(days), max(days)+1)]
[[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0)], 
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0)],
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0)],
 [],
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 5, 0, 0)]]
```

Another approach for making such groupings is *[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)*.  It is designed for this kind of work, but it doesn't provide a way to fill-in an empty list for missing days:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [list(group) for k, group in itertools.groupby(list_of_dts,
                                                   key=datetime.datetime.toordinal)]
[[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0)], 
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0)],
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0)],
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 5, 0, 0)]]
```

Comment: setdefault and toordinal are nice improvements over my answer. :-)

Comment: Even simpler than `setdefault` can be `defaultdict` (from `collections`).

Comment: Beautiful - thanks! I can generate my `days` list at the same time as my `list_of_dts`, so it will be super efficient.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to easily handle this kind of problems:

```
import datetime
import itertools

list_of_dts = [
        datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0), 
        datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,1,0,0), 
        datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,0,0,0), 
        datetime.datetime(2012,1,3,0,0,0),
        datetime.datetime(2012,1,5,0,0,0),
        ]

print [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(list_of_dts, key=lambda d: d.date())]
```

Comment: Good to know - thanks! It doesn't handle the requirement of an empty list for missing days, though.

Answer (score 1):

Filling the gaps:

```
date_dict = {}
for date_value in list_of_dates:
    if date_dict.has_key(date_value.date()):
        date_dict[date_value.date()].append(date_value)
    else:
        date_dict[date_value.date()] = [ date_value ]
sorted_dates = sorted(date_dict.keys())
date = sorted_dates[0]
while date <= sorted_dates[-1]:
    print date_dict.get(date, [])
    date += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Results:

```
[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0)]
[]
[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 5, 0, 0)]
```

This solution does not requires the original datetime list to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_dts = [
            datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0), 
            datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,1,0,0), 
            datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,0,0,0), 
            datetime.datetime(2012,1,3,0,0,0),
            datetime.datetime(2012,1,5,0,0,0),
            ]

groupedByDay={}
for date in list_of_dts:
    if date.date() in groupedByDay:
        groupedByDay[date.date()].append(date)
    else:
        groupedByDay[date.date()]=[date]
```

Now you have a dictionary, where the date is the key and the value is a list of similar dates.

and if you are set on having a list instead

```
result = groupedByDay.values()
result.sort()
```

now results is a list of lists, where all the dates with the same day are grouped together

Comment: `date.date() in groupedByDay.keys()` is O(n). Could you replace it with `date.date() in groupedByDay`? it's O(1).

Comment: done. Thanks for the tip. I just recently picked up python.. learn something new every day.